# Maximum Length Of Field Label and Field Name Properties and Possibility Of Customization

Tags: fields, label

Can Anyone Let me know the Maximum Length Of Field Lable and Field Name Properties  and is it possible to  customize it any way?

Answer (score 0):

Hurray… Got the  answer of first question maximum length of Field Label and Field Name is 40 Characters. Still waiting for second question's answer